# how to make collisions with skshapenode circles

Tags: geometry, sprite-kit, collision, skshapenode

I am working on a game that incorporates touch detection with skShapenodes that are circles, and can not find a good method to check if they are touching. Code for the player class is below

```
-(void)SpawnPlayer
{   
        _player = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

        CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddArc(myPath, NULL, 0,0, 15, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
        _player.path = myPath;

        _player.lineWidth = 1.0;
        _player.fillColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        _player.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        _player.glowWidth = 0.5;
        _location = CGPointMake(375, 400);
        _player.position = CGPointMake(375, 400);
        _player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:0.5];
        _player.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        _player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
        _player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory;
        _player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;


        [self addChild:_player];
}
```

The enemy code is similar, with the exception that its bitmask and testbitmask are switched.

Comment: the two contact bitmasks ANDed together must be non-zero to create a contact event - if you use different contact bitmasks they will not generate contact events

Comment: Sorry, I am a student and this is my first year using objective c, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as this:
The `categoryBitMask` specifies the type of body a node is.
The `collisionBitMask` specifies which type of bodies it can collide with.
The `contactTestBitMask` specifies which type of contactTestBitMasks will interact with it.

e.g. to detect contact between player and enemy, which have different categoryBitMasks, their contactTestBitMasks should be:

```
_player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
_player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | enemyCategory ;
```

For enemy:

```
 _enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
 _enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  playerCategory | enemyCategory ;
```

now you can handle what to do on contact in `didBeginContact` method